# Find the area of the Rose's petal.

Tags: polar-coordinates

> If a Rose leaf is described by the equation $r = \sin 3\theta$, find the area of one petal.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the area inside a polar-coordinate defined function?

Comment: The integration one? Then, yes but I don't know how to put limits. And how do I know what area of the petal is?

Comment: Draw at least part of the curve. Start at $\theta=0$ and move counterclockwise. There is a first return to the origin when $3\theta=\pi$.

Answer (score 8):

A sketch is useful here, but the only important observation is that $r=0$ when $\theta=0$, and again at $\frac{\pi}{3}$. These are your limits for one petal.

Since the area of a polar curve between the rays $\theta=a$ and $\theta=b$ is given by $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{2}r^{2}d\theta$, we have
$$A=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\frac{1}{2}\sin^{2}(3\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\frac{1-\cos(6\theta)}{2}d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left[\theta-\frac{\sin(6\theta)}{2}\right]^{\pi/3}_{0}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{6\pi}{3}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: m just confused how we notice that r=0..etc etc plz tell me a simple and unique way to solve such problems like roses ,polar quad etc etc ...

Comment: Alternately we could compute $\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(3\theta)d\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\Theta:\mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0} \to \mathbb{R}}$ is the
$Heaviside\ Step\ Function$. $\ds{\Theta\pars{x} = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < 0}
\\
\ds{1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > 0}
\end{array}\right.}$

---

$\ds{}$
With $x = r\cos\pars{\theta}$, $y = r\sin\pars{\theta}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large{\cal A}}
&\equiv
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{\theta}
\Theta\pars{\pi - 3\theta}\Theta\pars{\sin\pars{3\theta} - r}
\,\dd x\,\dd y
=
\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r\,
\Theta\pars{\sin\pars{3\theta} - r}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{\sin\pars{3\theta}}r\,\dd r
=
\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\half\,\sin^{2}\pars{3\theta}\,\dd\theta
=
\half\int_{0}^{\pi/3}{1 - \cos\pars{6\theta} \over 2}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 4}\bracks{{\pi \over 3} - {\sin\pars{2\pi} \over 6}}
=\color{#0000ff}{\large{\pi \over 12}}
\end{align}

Comment: Why are you multiplying the integrals?